# Use Excel Power Query to extract JSON data

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a spreadsheet with 5 columns.  One of those columns contains a json array (the array also has nested arrays).  Is it possible to use Power Query Editor to parse the json array in each row?  So that  each row has the four original columns plus the new columns for each value in the Json array and sub arrays?  While the data in each JSON array may be  unique, the structure is always the same, though the number of elements/sub arrays fluctuates.   Below is an example of the data I want to transform and how I would like to transform it.

**Data to be transformed**

| response_id | response_json |
| --- | --- |
| a476f978-430c-47fa-a2a4-7be0d863a69e | [{"sublist":false,"aggregate_category":"null_options","question":"some question."},{"sublist":[{"option_1":"some val","option_2":"another value","option_3":"more values"}],"aggregate_category":"has_options","question":"another question"},{"sublist":[],"aggregate_category":"empty_options","question":"another question"}] |

**Output**

| ID | aggregate_category | question | option_1 | option_2 | option_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a476f978-430c-47fa-a2a4-7be0d863a69e | null_options | some question. | null | null | null |
| a476f978-430c-47fa-a2a4-7be0d863a69e | has_options | some question. | some val | another value | more values |
| a476f978-430c-47fa-a2a4-7be0d863a69e | empty_options | some question. | null | null | null |

[image]

**Edit**
But, what happens is that, I can transform the initial json array and expand the rows.  But, the embeded json array (titled "sublist") cannot be transformed any further, because of the values that are either null or false.

I think that one issue is that while all rows have a json string, the field in the json array, titled `sublist` can be

```
sublist:[]
sublist:[{"option_1":1, "option_2: "aaa", option_3:""}]
sublist:false
```

I think the issue is when the value is :false, it can't be parsed.  So, maybe I have to put in the script, if the value is false, I have to put in fake data?  I have tried this but it fails:

=if [response_json.sublist] =  "false" then
"no data"
else Json.Document([response_json.sublist])

which I think could be because of the script is trying to parse something that is not there?

**Edit - Add advance editor code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("D:\Downloads\ExampleDataSet.xlsx"), null, true),
    Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item="Sheet1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Sheet1_Sheet,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}}),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Changed Type", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"response_id", type text}, {"response_json", type text}}),
    #"Parsed JSON" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type1",{{"response_json", Json.Document}}),
    #"Expanded response_json" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Parsed JSON", "response_json"),
    fixSublist = Table.TransformColumns(response_json,{"sublist", each if  _ = false then {} else _ }),
    #"Expanded response_json1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(fixSublist, "response_json", {"sublist", "aggregate_category", "question"}, {"response_json.sublist", "response_json.aggregate_category", "response_json.question"})
in
    #"Expanded response_json1"
```

**Edit Other solution**

In addition to the great help from Ron, I found that adding a custom column and adding this formula also worked:

```
=if [response_json.sublist] <> false then
Table.ToRecords(Table.FromRecords([response_json.sublist]))
else
Table.ToRecords(
    Table.FromRecords({
        [option_1 = "null", option_2 = "null", option_3 = "null"]    
    })
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Add a Custom Column:

[image]

```
Formula:  =Json.Document([JSON Field])
```

- Expand the resulting List columns into new rows; expand the resultant records column (and the sublist)
- Arrange and rename your columns as desired

***Edit: Response to your M Code posting***

- You have bad references and you have the "fixSublist" line in the wrong place
- Please step through the Applied Steps and read the comments in the code to better understand what is going on at each step.
- Since I obtained the initial table from an open Workbook and not a file, the first few lines of my M code are different.

**Data**
[image]

**M Code**

```
let

//Next two lines different due to my source being a table in an open workbook and not a file
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"response_id", type text}, {"response_json", type text}}),
    #"Parsed JSON" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type1",{{"response_json", Json.Document}}),

//expand the subtables/records/lists
    #"Expanded response_json" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Parsed JSON", "response_json"),
    #"Expanded response_json2" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded response_json", "response_json", 
        {"sublist", "aggregate_category", "question"}, {"sublist", "aggregate_category", "question"}),

//Now that the sublists are exposed we can fix the entries that are not Lists
    fixSublist = Table.TransformColumns(#"Expanded response_json2",{"sublist", each if  _ = false then {} else _ }),

//Now expand them
    #"Expanded sublist" = Table.ExpandListColumn(fixSublist, "sublist"),
    #"Expanded sublist1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded sublist", "sublist", {"option_1", "option_2", "option_3"}, {"option_1", "option_2", "option_3"})
in
    #"Expanded sublist1"
```

**Results**
[image]

Comment: Thank you Ron.  This worked for the first level of json data.  When I follow your steps and the results are expanded, I am provided with all the new columns.  The new column with the second level of json data says "list" in each record.  I  then try to create a new column based on that.  But, when I create the column, the new column has "Error" in every cell.  The error says" Expression.Error: the parameter is expected to be of type Text.Type or Binary.Type.  Details: [List]".  What am I doing wrong on the second json array?

Comment: I think I found the issue.  On occasion, the sub array will have sublist:false instead of sublist:[].  Is there a way to skip the json formatting process for the sub array if it is "False"?  Or, is this something I would need to do before bringing into Excel PQ?

Comment: @jason You should be able to handle it within PQ.  What, exactly, does that JSON string segment look like?

Comment: @jason Also, how are you trying to handle it?  From the UI or are you writing M Code directly.  If the latter, what is the code you are using?  If the former, I'm surprised because if I change one entry to `sublist:"false"` I do not  have the option to expand that column

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have updated my question with more details.  I have tried both the GUI and by creating a custom column and creating a custom column formula (I added an example in the update).  I think it might be because the code wants to extract a json string that is not there?

Comment: @jason Again, I cannot reproduce your problem. If I have `sublist:false` on one item, I am not given the option to expand that column in the UI.  You could try inserting this line (using the `Advanced Editor`, in the line before you first expand the sublist:  `fixSublist = Table.TransformColumns(previousStep,{"sublist", each if  _ = false then {} else _ }),` previousStep is the name of the step just before where you insert this; on the next step change the reference from `*previousStep*` to `fixSublist`; and the column name in Previous step is expected to be `subList`.

Comment: I apologize for all the back and forth.  I am new to Excel Power Query.  I have updated my question with an exact and concise data set I am using (one row with two columns).  I also added a screen grab of what it looks like when I expand the first json array, and how I can't expand the second.  I hope this helps in re-creating.  I know there is a lot of back and forth on this, so I am happy to donate some reputation points if that helps?  I will also try the suggestion you gave

Comment: And I think I misread your last comment.  If you are saying you cannot unpack the json array if sublist:false, that is exactly the issue.  Some sublist json arrays will not have an array, which seems to be causing the problem

Comment: @jason I misinterpreted your comment. When you wrote every cell showed error when you try to expand that column, I thought you were trying to expand the column using the interface. Clearly you were trying something else. And in any event my solution posted above in my comments should work. If you have trouble implementing it, I will need to see your m code - copy paste from the advanced editor.

Comment: sorry, it took me awhile to figure out what Advanced Editor is and how to get to it.  I have updated my question with the current Advance Editor Code.

Comment: @jason See my edited answer

Comment: Thanks for your help with this!  I also found that doing a custom column was able to do this as well.  I added that in my edits.

Comment: @jason The custom column should work also, and good experience devising it! But I would think that just changing false to a null list with a columnTransform, then expanding the column, might be more efficient (I don't know for sure, as I have not tested it).